# How to add 'Name' header to embedded image in EmailMessage

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email with embedded image(Not as attachment file). I am able to send mail.

I'm sending mail using following code:

```
internal static void Send(SmtpServerConfigurations configurations, EmailMessage emailMsg)
{
    using (var mail = InitializeMailMessage(emailMsg))
    using (var smtpClient = CreateSmtpClient(configurations))
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
}

private static MailMessage InitializeMailMessage(EmailMessage emailMsg)
{
    var mail = new MailMessage
               {
                   From = new MailAddress(emailMsg.From),
                   Subject = emailMsg.Subject,
                   IsBodyHtml = emailMsg.IsBodyHtml
               };

    mail.To.Add(emailMsg.To);

    AddMessageBody(emailMsg, mail);

    return mail;
}

private static void AddMessageBody(EmailMessage emailMsg, MailMessage mail)
{
    if (emailMsg.IsBodyHtml)
    {
        var body = GetHtmlBody(emailMsg.Body, emailMsg.EmbeddedImages);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(body);
    }
    else
        mail.Body = emailMsg.Body;
}

private static AlternateView GetHtmlBody(string body, List<EmbeddedImage> embeddedImages)
{
    var alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null,
        MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

    if (embeddedImages == null) return alternateView;

    foreach (var image in embeddedImages)
    {
        var imageToInline = new LinkedResource(image.Path, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        imageToInline.ContentId = image.Id;
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToInline);
    }
    return alternateView;
}

private static SmtpClient CreateSmtpClient(SmtpServerConfigurations config)
{
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(config.Host);
    smtpClient.Port = config.PortNo;

    if (config.IsAuthenticationRequired)
        smtpClient.Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential(config.Username, config.Password);
    else
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
    return smtpClient;
}
```

But the mail sent using above code is not in the format as I want.

**What I want is;**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: x@y.com
To: a@b.com
Date: 11 Nov 2016 11:37:52 +0530
Subject: This is subject
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary=--boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d; type="text/html"


----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "=
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xm=
lns =3D "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head ><meta http - equi=
v =3D "content-type" content =3D "text/html; charset=3DUTF-8" /><=
/head ><body style =3D"font-family: Segoe UI; text-align:left;" >=
This is body<br /><img alt =3D"" src =3D"cid:05393c56-15c1-4652-a=
31f-9cc513726bc0" height=3D"50" width=3D"50"/></body ></html >
----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d
Content-Type: image/jpeg    name="filename.jpg"            <<-----This is what I want.
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <05393c56-15c1-4652-a31f-9cc513726bc0>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMF
BwYHBwcGBwcI
.
.
.
/w20K7sPt8ul2st3/z0dd36Hj9K9I+HHwj8M6/rLaldaJp8l6y
kGRYgn6LgfpXve0pundwQmk9z//Z
----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d--
```

**What I am getting is;**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: x@y.com
To: a@b.com
Date: 11 Nov 2016 11:37:52 +0530
Subject: This is subject
Content-Type: multipart/related;
 boundary=--boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d; type="text/html"


----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC " -//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "=
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xm=
lns =3D "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > <head ><meta http - equi=
v =3D "content-type" content =3D "text/html; charset=3DUTF-8" /><=
/head ><body style =3D"font-family: Segoe UI; text-align:left;" >=
This is body<br /><img alt =3D"" src =3D"cid:05393c56-15c1-4652-a=
31f-9cc513726bc0" height=3D"50" width=3D"50"/></body ></html >
----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <05393c56-15c1-4652-a31f-9cc513726bc0>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMF
BwYHBwcGBwcI
.
.
.
/w20K7sPt8ul2st3/z0dd36Hj9K9I+HHwj8M6/rLaldaJp8l6y
kGRYgn6LgfpXve0pundwQmk9z//Z
----boundary_3_1bb3db0a-d33f-46a7-a6ce-60249096160d--
```

How can I achieve that custom "Name" header in Embedded image section of raw mail?

I want to add that header is because;

When I click on download button shown on image in Gmail inbox, I get "noname" file without extension. That downloaded file isn't useful unless user changes its extension to '.jpg/.jpeg'. 
[image: Download image button on gmail]

When I tried the same with another component(Which I don't have code for) strangely I was able to download that image with correct filename. Only difference between these two mails was "Name" header.

Please suggest me how to do this or any other way to achieve it.

Comment: You didn't show any code so impossible to say what's wrong

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, I have added my code to send email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick for you

```
imageToInline.ContentType.Name = "ImageName.jpg";
```

Comment: Felt happy to help. :)